# 403 Forbidden with correct permissions

Tags: nginx

I'm getting 403 forbidden although my permissions and configs seem correct. What could be wrong.

File permissions

[image]

Nginx config

[image]

Comment: Try adding to your empty `location /` block (in between the brackets) to show default type and root. So it looks like this : https://i.imgur.com/ZkGhKuY.png

Comment: Also run `nginx -t` or `sudo nginx -t` and make sure it says "test successful" with no errors, if it does have errors share what they are.

Comment: @Bman70 I did exactly what you suggested and test was successful the result is the same

Comment: You have to reload or restart nginx after every change in order for nginx to pick it up. Other than that, not sure what else to try.

Comment: @Bman70 my website contains js code does that need to include any js modules

Comment: Try this: Change the server root to `root /usr/share/nginx/html;` (Take off "website".)  Make the location root `/usr/share/nginx/html/website;` (As shown in my image.) No slash at the end.

Comment: In addition to my above new comment, directory permissions are different from file permissions and can be set to `rwxr-xr-x` (755). So make sure your website directories have that, while the files inside stay at ` rw-r--r--`.